# Absolute selection to relative selection using $(this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Say there is a selector `$("#someID p")` and that `$(this)` = `$("#someID")`.  What selector would always be equal (if it was more complicated, like the example below) starting with `$(this).`

Example:

I have the following selector:  `$(tableMap.id + " tr:eq(" + i + ") td:eq(" + j + ")")`

On that line, I have `$(this)` being equal to `$(tableMap.id)`.

How would I remove `tableMap.id` from the first line and still keep the rest of the selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(this).find("tr:eq(" + i + ") td:eq(" + j + ")")
```

or

```
$("tr:eq(" + i + ") td:eq(" + j + ")", this)
```

Reference: [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: +1 - I think this is what the OP was asking, but the question is really not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna use element id, you need to provide full specific selector, take a look at this question: [Get CSS path from Dom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620116/get-css-path-from-dom-element)