# Jxbrowser: get image width and height from DOMElement

Tags: image, jxbrowser, ixmldomelement

How can I get the clientwidth and clientheight if I have a list of img

```
imgs = document.findElements(By.cssSelector("a>img"));
for(DOMElemnt img:imgs){
double height =img.getAttribute("height");//not always works ,sometime return null value
//What API can I use?
}
```

Or should I use jquery? but how can it combined with jxbrowser API?
Thanks!

Comment: Are `img` separated by some `attribute` from each other? for example with `id` or `class` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no API for getting an element's `height` or `width` directly. I give two methods to get `height` and `width`. Use each that matches your code.

1. If there is some attribute that separates images from each other such as `id`, then you can get image `width` and `height` using `.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue` method:

   ```
   for(DOMElemnt img : imgs){
       JSValue res = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue(
                       "["
                     + "document.getElementById('" + img.getAttribute("id") + "').width,"
                     + "document.getElementById('" + img.getAttribute("id") + "').height,"
                     + "]");
       if (res.isArray()) {            
           JSArray attrs = res.asArray();                          
           if (attrs.get(0).isNumber()) {          
               float width = attrs.get(0).asNumber().getFloat();
               // use width variable
           }
           if (attrs.get(1).isNumber()) {              
               float height = attrs.get(1).asNumber().getFloat();
               // use height variable
           }

       }
   }
   ```
2. If images do not have such attribute to separate them, you can call a function in javascript which returns an array of elements and every element consists of css path, width and height. By doing so, you can access images width and height directly. Also the css path can be used to access `DOMElement`. First of all, add this script to your html :

   ```
   <script>
   var cssPath = function(el) {
       if (!(el instanceof Element)) 
           return;
       var path = [];
       while (el.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
           var selector = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
           if (el.id) {
               selector += '#' + el.id;
               path.unshift(selector);
               break;
           } else {
               var sib = el, nth = 1;
               while (sib = sib.previousElementSibling) {
                   if (sib.nodeName.toLowerCase() == selector)
                       nth++;
               }
               if (el.previousElementSibling != null || el.nextElementSibling != null)
                   selector += ":nth-of-type("+nth+")";
           }
           path.unshift(selector);
           el = el.parentNode;
       }
       return path.join(" > ");
   };
   var getArray = function(selector) {
       var images = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
       var result = [];
       for (i = 0; i < images.length; ++i)
           result.push({'path': cssPath(images[i]), 'width' : images[i].width, 'height': images[i].height});
       return result;
   };
   </script>
   ```

   `cssPath` function takes an element and returns css path string. The code is just copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620116/get-css-path-from-dom-element) (asselin's answer) with a little modification(replaced `if (nth != 1)` with `if (el.previousElementSibling != null || el.nextElementSibling != null)`). function `getArray` takes a selector sting and iterates through `querySelectorAll()` result, adding every element's `width`, `height` and css path.

   Then call `getArray` function from java and parse the result:

   ```
   JSValue result = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("getArray('a > img');");

   if (result.isArray()) {

       JSArray res_arr = result.asArray();

       for (int i = 0 ; i < res_arr.length() ; i++) {

           if (res_arr.get(i).isObject()) {

               JSObject obj = res_arr.get(i).asObject();

               float width = obj.getProperty("width").asNumber().getFloat();
               float height = obj.getProperty("height").asNumber().getFloat();
               String path = obj.getProperty("path").getStringValue();

               DOMElement elem = doc.findElement(By.cssSelector(path));
               // use anything of elem you need            
           }       
       }
   }
   ```

   - Make sure that frame has finished loading when you call javascript functions, here `getArray`. For that you can use call `addLoadListener` on `browser` and pass it a `LoadAdapter`. Then using `onFinishLoadingFrame` method of adapter.

Comment: Thank you so much! that's a great solution

Comment: Yours, Hope it helps :)