# Selecting div by ID from array of divs using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have added several div elements to a variable to cache them.

```
[
    div#description.tab__content,
    div#reviews.tab__content,
    div#delivery.tab__content,
    div#returns.tab__content,
]
```

Using jQuery how would I select the #description div from the array?

The ordering of the elements cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: I know its a rather old post, but perhaps some of the answers there will be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620116/get-css-path-from-dom-element

Comment: Assuming that's a jquery collection of dom elements, just use `whateverYourCollectionIsCalled.filter('#description')`

Answer (score 1):

I think you could cache your elements in an object and query them as needed. Your object could look like:

```
var cache = {
    "#description": div#description.tab__content,
    "#reviews": div.#reviewstab__content,
    "#delivery": div#delivery.tab__content,
    "#returns": div#returns.tab__content,
}
```

cache[id] can be reused.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the class names in the array. Use ids only.

Since "the ordering of the elements cannot be guaranteed", use the `indexOf()` method to determine the element's *position in the array*. Then select the element:

```js
var divs = [
    'div#reviews',
    'div#description',
    'div#delivery',
    'div#returns'
];

// get the element's position (index)
var divIdx = divs.indexOf('div#description');

console.log(divs[divIdx] + ' has the index ' + divIdx);

// select the element from the array
var $description = $(divs[divIdx]);
 
// do stuff with the element
$description.addClass('active');
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.tab__content {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.tab__content.active {
  background: #efefef;
}
.tab__content h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.tab__content p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="reviews" class="tab__content">
  <h2>Reviews</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam totam odit voluptas veniam illo saepe vel similique assumenda, dignissimos iste aperiam aliquid dolore esse atque inventore officiis enim id natus?</p>
</div>

<div id="description" class="tab__content">
  <h2>Description</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam totam odit voluptas veniam illo saepe vel similique assumenda, dignissimos iste aperiam aliquid dolore esse atque inventore officiis enim id natus?</p>
</div>

<div id="delivery" class="tab__content">
  <h2>Delivery</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam totam odit voluptas veniam illo saepe vel similique assumenda, dignissimos iste aperiam aliquid dolore esse atque inventore officiis enim id natus?</p>
</div>

<div id="returns" class="tab__content">
  <h2>Returns</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam totam odit voluptas veniam illo saepe vel similique assumenda, dignissimos iste aperiam aliquid dolore esse atque inventore officiis enim id natus?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to search in the array, like this:

```js
var a = $('div');
$.each(a, function(index, value) {
  if(value.id === 'test3')
    console.log('found '+value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" class="test"></div>
<div id="test2" class="test2"></div>
<div id="test3" class="test3"></div>
<div id="test4" class="test4"></div>
<div id="test5" class="test5"></div>
```

I hope that I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood your needs if I am not wrong then following snippet will be helpful for you.

```js
var array = [
              'div#div1',
              'div#div2',
              'div#div3',
              'div#div4'
            ];
            
$('#btnShow').click(function(){
  for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
    $(array[i]).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" style="display:none">
    Container 1  
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">
    Container 2
</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:none">
    Container 3  
</div>
<div id="div4" style="display:none">
    Container 3  
</div>


<button id="btnShow">Show Containers</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick function that loops through the array and tries to find the string you enter as a needle. [Try it out on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3bdLx08/3/)

```
var list = [
  "div#description.tab__content",
  "div#reviews.tab__content",
  "div#delivery.tab__content",
  "div#returns.tab__content"
];

function findElement(needle, haystack) {
  var regex = new RegExp(needle, 'i');
  var result = null;

  haystack.forEach(function(value) {
    if (value.match(regex)) {
      result = value;
    }
  });

  return result;
}

jQuery(findElement('description', list))
```