# CSS pseudo-selector to select the current element within querySelector usable for the sibling (+) or general sibling (~) selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, siblings

If I have this HTML:

```
<div class="elem">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="sibling">
</div>
```

and the JS

```
let elem = document.querySelector('.elem');
```

Using `elem.querySelector(":scope ~ div")` does not return anything even though there are `div` siblings of elem.

Using `elem.querySelector(":scope > div")` returns an element because also there are are `div` children of elem.

How could I select the current sibling of `elem` having the js object
for elem already selected in a js variable (`let elem = document.querySelector('.elem')`)?

Comment: Please post your HTML or DOM structure.

Comment: Note that `~` actually selects **subsequent** siblings, not **previous** siblings. CSS is strictly "forward-only".

Comment: and how could i select the sibling of current element, elem, using querySelector ?

Comment: The reference element pseudo-class `:scope` seems to be incompatible with the next-sibling combinator `+` or with the subsequent-sibling combinator `~`. I have no answer to this about why.

Comment: **Answer**: The reference element pseudo-class `:scope` define a scoping-root and thus any matched element "must be within the scope". A sibling is not in the scope (aka: descendant) of the `:scope`. This is why it does not apply. https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#scoping-root https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#the-scope-pseudo

Comment: Not a duplicate, see comment about the scope of `:scope`